# Make my website dynamically loaded data available to Facebook Open Graph Object Scrapper

Tags: javascript, facebook, open-graph-protocol

Here is the design of my web site:

1. The user enter `myWebsite.com/a/1`
2. .htaccess rules redirect to `myWebsite.com/b`
3. Now the JavaScript ExtJS library is loading.
4. Extracting the value from the URL (in this case it is “1”)
5. Loading `./xml/1.xml`
6. From `1.xml` setting the Open Graph data (Title, type, image, etc)
7. Loading data that will be shown to the user from `1.xml` into the website.

My question is:

How can I make the Open Graph data available to Facebook? Facebook do not to load my ExtJS JavaScript Library before extracting the Open Graph Object values from the HTML. Is there an easy solution to this problem? The only solutions I found is to make statics web pages or dynamically pages rendered on the server side but I would like to avoid these since my web page implementation is already finished and I would like to avoid re working on it.

Answer (score 1):

As you already mentioned you have to generate the pages dynamically for the [facebook user agent](https://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)

The facebook bot is not possible to parse javascript (like google or bing bot too)